# How to add dynamic filter in Power Query

Tags: excel, filter, powerquery

I want to filter one table by using a column in another table. Here is my table to be filtered:

**Table 1**

```
deviceid, user_number  
001,400
002,500
003,600
004,700
009,1000
```

I have another table:

**Table 2**

```
deviceid
001
003
004
```

Now I can filter table 1 with table 2 by writing something like this:

```
"Filtered Rowxx" = Table.SelectRows(#"Column1", each ([deviceid] <> "001" 
and [deviceid] <> "003" and [deviceid] <> "004")
```

Since Table 2 changes all the time, how can I define a query under power query to achieve this please?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want an anti-join.

`Table.Join` with `JoinKind.LeftAnti` will filter out rows from the left table that match the right table.

```
let
    Column1= #table({"deviceid", "user_number"}, { {"001", "400"}, {"002", "500"}, {"003", "600"}, {"004", "700"}, {"009", "1000"} }),
    Table2 = #table({"__deviceid"}, { {"001"}, {"003"}, {"004"} }),

    AntiJoin = Table.Join(#"Column1", "deviceid", Table2, "__deviceid", JoinKind.LeftAnti),
    SelectColumns = Table.SelectColumns(AntiJoin, {"user_number", "deviceid"})
in
    SelectColumns
```

One benefit of `Table.Join` is it's likely to fold your filter to a backing relational database server, while list operations tend not to fold. (But if your query runs quickly, it doesn't really matter.)

One problem with `Table.Join` is it can't handle multiple columns with the same name, so I had to rename the Table2's "deviceid" column.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the column deviceid of Table2 by using `Table2[deviceid]`, which gives you a list. We can check if the current deviceid is in the list with `List.Contains`, so your filter can look something like this:

`"Filtered Rowxx" = Table.SelectRows(#"Column1", each not List.Contains(Table2[deviceid], [deviceid]))`

Comment: thanks for your answer!@Alejandro Lopez-Lago - MSFT, I tried this today, since my table 1 has more than 200 000 rows, it took really longtime to execute the query and ended up with an error:Failed to load into Data model. Do you know any other way to achieve this, thanks in advance

Comment: Actually I was wandering were there a fonction for creating a string of filter from a column,--------- like create a string from table 1 deviceid column,  [deviceid] <> "001" and [deviceid] <> "003" and [deviceid] <> "004"